# In Windows, what is an auxiliary performance counter?

Tags: winapi, performancecounter

Windows provides a number of documented APIs relating to the "auxiliary counter" aka "auxiliary performance counter".

In user-mode, [`QueryAuxiliaryCounterFrequency`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/realtimeapiset/nf-realtimeapiset-queryauxiliarycounterfrequency), [`ConvertAuxiliaryCounterToPerformanceCounter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/realtimeapiset/nf-realtimeapiset-convertauxiliarycountertoperformancecounter), [`ConvertPerformanceCounterToAuxiliaryCounter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/realtimeapiset/nf-realtimeapiset-convertperformancecountertoauxiliarycounter) (all defined in `realtimeapiset.h`). And, in kernel-mode (for driver developers), there are the corresponding APIs [`KeQueryAuxiliaryCounterFrequency`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-kequeryauxiliarycounterfrequency), [`KeConvertAuxiliaryCounterToPerformanceCounter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-keconvertperformancecountertoauxiliarycounter) and [`KeConvertPerformanceCounterToAuxiliaryCounter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-keconvertauxiliarycountertoperformancecounter)

But, what is an auxiliary counter? And why would you want to use one? And how do you actually read the value of an auxiliary counter? The documentation doesn't answer any of these questions.

Comment: You can submit the concern to Microsoft through the document feedback button.